# Update OpenCV version in ROS

Tags: ros, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I checked my OpenCV version discovering that is 2.4.8.
I want to update it to 2.4.13 (at least 2.4.9) but I don't want to stop to use it in ROS Indigo too.

Since OpenCV is not a system dependencies anymore for Indigo, can I simply remove the old version of OpenCV and install a new one without "break" ROS Indigo?

Anyone knows if other actions are required?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248457/update-opencv-version-in-ros/) by [marcoresk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28398/marcoresk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can locally upgrade any package. But you will potentially have to rebuild all packages built against that package if the ABI has changed. Otherwise it will be fine.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-30**:
Related: #q289264. I've also described how to update a system dependency and then rebuild packages that depend on it.